# strange byte diffence- is this impossible

Tags: encoding, cygwin

In cygwin, I have two almost identical files, the other one I did minimal modification. And on the screen the first line is identical. So I use cmp utility to compare these two files byte by byte.

```
$cat double.c

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static GLfloat spin = 0.0;

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}
........

$cat double1.c

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static GLfloat spin = 0.0;

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
}
...........


$cmp double.c double1.c
```

It outputs these:

```
double.c double1.c diffrent: line 8 char 125
```

So

```
$cmp -l double.c double1.c
```

It output these:

```
 125  12  40
 126 173  12
 127  12 173
 128  40  12
 144  50  40
 145  60  50
 146  56  60
.........
```

12 is "new line", 40 is ")" and 173 is "{"

the difference in a Windows editor is illustrated as following

[image: the difference in a Windows editor is illustrated here]

So how this difference come from? I am confused.

double.c
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5qhYcc2Fk0sZmEySUNIc1RzM3M/edit?usp=sharing

double1.c
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5qhYcc2Fk0sRTdoV1RDNnB2QkU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's probably some kinda user mistake (these do happen, even to the best of us). Can you copy the files to a separate directory, name them 1 & 2, and still see this difference in a repeatable manner?